# Password protect an individual table in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, password-protection

I am transitioning a project from Advantage Database Server to MS SQL server.  In Advantage, you can password protect an individual table, which is also encrypted.  As such, you cannot open, view, update, etc. the table without the password.  I place my project's registration information in this table, so I don't want any user to be able to look at its contents.

I cannot find a similar function in SQL server.  Encrypting the data is insufficient.  So my question is:  is there a way to password protect a table in SQL Server.

Comment: you can try restricting permissions in sql server

Comment: You need to encrypt your information programatically.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server you can link various access roles to the users. These roles can be applied to tables, views, stored procedures etc. The best thing to do is to create views on the database, and let the users access specific views, rather than giving permissions on all DB objects.

Alternatively, you can deny permissions on a specific table to a user or a role.

Here are two articles on MSDN that will get you started:

- [GRANT Object Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql)
- [DENY Object Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-object-permissions-transact-sql)